# Why does term get inserted twice when using dynamic slug?

Tags: terms

I'd like to dynamically generate the slug for a term. But I always end up with 2 entries in the database.

I came up this minimal working example:
When I run this code below, I end up with 2 entries in the database

e.g.

```
term_id  name   slug  
284      test   list-66603_1610659731  
285      test   list-29853_1610659732
```

*submit-list.php*:

```php
function test_submit_list()
{
    $slug = 'list-'. random_int(1,100000) .'_'. time();

    $term = wp_insert_term(
        'test',
        'list',
        array(
            'description' => 'Slug: "'.$slug.'"',
            'slug'        => $slug,
            'parent'      => 25,
            )
    );
}
```

*index.php*:

```php
// add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_test_submit_list', 'test_submit_list' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test_submit_list', 'test_submit_list' );
include('submit-list.php');
```

The function is called by an AJAX:

```js
$("#list-form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = {
            action: 'test_submit_list',
        };

        $.post(test_obj.ajax_url, form).always(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

When I change the first line to `$slug = 'list-'. 12345 .'_'. 11111111;`, I only get one entry.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on? This is driving me crazy.

### Update

I did some more testing, but I still haven't found what is causing the behavior.

- I exported the AJAX call and triggered it via Postman. Then only one entry is inserted.
- I replaced triggering the AJAX call not by the submit button, but another element with ID tag and click event
- I rewrote the JS, to replace jQuery with vanilla JS and put the call in its own function:

  ```js
  function submitTerm() {
      const data = new FormData();

      data.append( 'action', 'test_submit_list' );
      fetch(test_obj.ajax_url, {
          method: "POST",
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          body: data
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
          if (data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  Still the same behavior (2 entries)
- Just calling the `submitTerm()`in the script (after the document is loaded, but not click event to trigger the function)
  also 2 entries
- when I call `submitTerm()` in der Browser console, there is only 1 entry

So, somehow the AJAX call is made twice, whenever it's called through the JS script.

Comment: If the slug isn't dynamic then you wouldn't be able to see if the same term was being inserted twice because the second one would fail. So it's not actually solving the problem, it's just hiding it. Check the network tab your browser console when submitting the form to see if you AJAX request is only sent once, or if it's being sent twice or more.

Comment: In addition to what Jacob said, you should consider using the REST API to create the term. But yes, if the double term creation is because of a JS in the active theme, a plugin or some custom code, then even with the REST API, you'd still get the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. In the network tab the request to `admin-ajax.php` is only made once. The `console.log(data)` in the js console is also only printed once (with the term ID of the earlier term, i.e. 284)

Comment: But I guess the culprit must be in calling the `test_submit_list` method. @Sally I will look into using the REST API

Comment: @jost21, your code looks good to me, so maybe you should try deactivating plugins and see if the same issue persists. You can also try changing the form `id` to `list-form2` or something else.

Comment: @Sally There are no plugins activated

Comment: In that case, then it's probably a theme issue, particularly because you said, "*whenever it's called through the JS script*" - which shouldn't happen. So try your code with a default theme like Twenty Twenty-One. If you still get 2 entries, then maybe you'd want to try reinstalling WordPress (via the Dashboard → Updates page)..

Comment: Somehow it works now, I have no idea why. Probably one of the things I tried, and maybe because of caching, it didn't show right away. Anyhow, thanks for the help, I will try to find the exact culprit when I have some spare time.